# problems with multiple elements in wsdl soap request

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm having problems getting multiple elements in an wsdl soap request to work.  When I try the following conversion directly on the webservicex site directly, I get the current currency conversion.  When I try and do the same thing inside an app script, it always returns "0" for the rate.  What am I missing here?

```
function getCurrencyConversion2(){
  var fromCurr = "USD";
  var toCurr = "AUD";
  var wsdl = SoapService.wsdl("http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx?WSDL");
  Logger.log(wsdl.getServiceNames());
  var currencyService = wsdl.getService("CurrencyConvertor");
  Logger.log(currencyService.getOperationNames());
  //var convertOp = currencyService.getOperation("ConversionRate");
  var param = Xml.element("ConversionRate", [
                                  Xml.attribute("xmlns", "http://www.webservicex.net/"),
                                  Xml.element("FromCurrency", [fromCurr]),
                                  Xml.element("ToCurrency", [toCurr])
             ]);
  var result = currencyService.invokeOperation("ConversionRate", [param]);

  return;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are going to love this one. Stumped me for quite a while too.

The issue is that the attribute of `xmlns` is case sensitive. You were adding it as `http://www.webservicex.net/` when the right version is `http://www.webserviceX.NET/`. Notice the `X.NET` at the end.

The following tweaked version should work fine (logs XML with 0.9602 as the exchange rate).

```
function getCurrencyConversion2(){
  var fromCurr = "USD";
  var toCurr = "AUD";
  var wsdl = SoapService.wsdl("http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx?WSDL");
  var currencyService = wsdl.getService("CurrencyConvertor");
  var param = Xml.element("ConversionRate", [
                                  Xml.attribute("xmlns", "http://www.webserviceX.NET/"),
                                  Xml.element("FromCurrency", [fromCurr]),
                                  Xml.element("ToCurrency", [toCurr])
             ]);
  var result = currencyService.invokeOperation("ConversionRate", [param]);
  Logger.log(result.toXmlString());
  return;
}
```

This was painful due to the complexity of SOAP and the fact that this service didn't return a valuable error message.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond.   I never would have guessed case was the problem.  All the books, tutorials and forums I've looked at and none mentioned "oh by the way, xmlns is case sensitive, unlike normal URL's.

Comment: No, problem. Please mark the response as accepted to people know that complex type params work as intended.